# java runtime environment archive

Tags: java

Where can I take previous jre distributions?

I have found this place: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

But it seems to miss several distributions: update 8, update 12.

Also I checked http://java.com/ru/download/windows_xpi.jsp and latest update is 15, so why archive does not contain update 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they were never released. Check out the release history [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_7_updates).